# distribution among given list of user

Tags: c#, algorithm, c#-4.0, distribution

I have a requirement where I have a list of entity and users who that entity can be assigned

> E1 can be distributed by U1 or U2
>
> E2 must be distributed by U5
>
> E3 can be distributed by U2 or U3 or U4

I have such 50K entities and for each entity there might be 1 or more users. In case of 1 user, its clear and entity will be assigned to that user only. In case of multiple users, it can be assigned to any one them.

We want to distribute it such that each user gets equal amount of entities. and there are minimal possible/unavoidable skewed distributions, also each user might already posses some entities : U1 has 2K and U2 has 3K entitis already, so the distribution should take care of this fact as well.

**EDIT 1**

We have already tried a solution of going sequentially and assigning one entity at a time as per the allocation to users at that point in time, but that producing skewed results, because we are getting users who have less allocation earlier but more allocation later or viceversa...

> E1 to E25 "must be handled by any of" U1 & U2
>
> E26 to E50 "must be handled by any of" U2 & U3

if we go sequentially, in the end : U1 gets 12 (from E1-E25), U2 gets 19 (13 from E1-E25 & 6 from E26-E50) & U3 gets 19(from E26-E50). 
So all in all 50 allocated. fine. but see the skewed results

**EDIT2**

Why do we have different users per entity? there are multiple products to be distributed. Some users handle multiple products and some users handle single product, but still all the users need to be load balanced.

Comment: Why are the second set of 25 entities in your edit only distributed between U2 and U3?

Comment: there is some logic, internal to application.

Comment: Well then your comment "where the above simple logic, which I also implemented" on andrerpena's answer is wrong.  That logic either needs to be explained, or changed to something more reasonable.

Comment: what I meant there is, sequential distribution, does not work

Comment: It might work if you don't arbitrarily restrict the way you apply it using your "logic internal to the application".

Comment: agree.. it will work, if not restricted.. BUT the requirement needs it to restrict to certain users per entity... each users work on multiple products and they need to be load balanced, so the list of first 25 is for one product and another 25 is for another product. some users work on multiple products, some dont... still all needs to be load balanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in a couple of steps

1. Allocate all the entities with only one user
2. Allocate the remaining entities sequentially
3. Balance out entities between the users
4. Fix remaining issue by distributing any differences

**Original Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

    public class Entity
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public User()
        {
            EntitiesCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        }
        public string userId { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, int> EntitiesCount { get; set; }
        public int TotalEntities { get; set; }
        public bool Ignored { get; set; }

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            for (var myLoop = 0; myLoop < 100; myLoop++)
            {
                //Create users
                var userList = new List<User> {
                    new User { userId = "U0" } ,
                    new User { userId = "U1" } ,
                    new User { userId = "U2" } ,
                    new User { userId = "U3" } ,
                    new User { userId = "U4" } 
                };
                userList = userList.OrderBy(u => u.userId).ToList();
                //Assign Users to Entities
                var entityUsers = new Dictionary<string, List<User>>() { 
                    { "E0", 
                      new List<User> { 
                          userList[0] ,
                          userList[1] 
                      } 
                    } ,
                    { "E1", 
                      new List<User> { 
                          userList[4]
                      } 
                    } ,
                    { "E2", 
                      new List<User> { 
                          userList[1],
                          userList[2],
                          userList[3] 
                      } 
                    } 
                };


                //var entityUsers = new Dictionary<string, List<User>>() { 
                //        { "E0", 
                //          new List<User> { 
                //              userList[0] ,
                //              userList[1] 
                //          } 
                //        } ,
                //        { "E1", 
                //          new List<User> { 
                //              userList[1],
                //              userList[2],
                //          } 
                //        } ,
                //    };

                //Load Entities, you can change the number of entities generated her
                var entities = GenerateEntities(entityUsers.Count(), 50000);

                //Group the Entities by their type and display total number
                var lookupEntities = entities.ToLookup(e => e.Type);
                foreach (var lookupEntity in lookupEntities)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(lookupEntity.Key + " has " + lookupEntity.Count());
                }


                // Users are ignored if there is a one to one mapping
                var ignoreUsers = 0;

                //Entities are ignored if they are only handled by one user
                var ignoreEntities = 0;

                foreach (var entityUser in entityUsers)
                {
                    foreach (var user in entityUser.Value)
                    {
                        user.EntitiesCount.Add(entityUser.Key, 0);
                    }
                }

                //Assign entities where only one user available
                foreach (var entityUser in entityUsers.Where(a => a.Value.Count == 1))
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Assigning all " + entityUser.Key + " to " + entityUser.Value[0].userId + " - " + lookupEntities[entityUser.Key].Count());

                    entityUser.Value[0].TotalEntities += lookupEntities[entityUser.Key].Count();
                    entityUser.Value[0].EntitiesCount[entityUser.Key] = lookupEntities[entityUser.Key].Count();

                    //Ignore these entities because they cannot changed
                    ignoreEntities += entityUser.Value[0].TotalEntities;

                    if (entityUsers.Count(e => e.Value.Contains(entityUser.Value[0])) == 1)
                    {
                        //The user is only assigned to this one entity so ignore user in balancing
                        ignoreUsers++;
                        entityUser.Value[0].Ignored = true;
                    }
                }



                //Assign entities where more than one user available
                foreach (var entityUser in entityUsers.Where(a => a.Value.Count > 1))
                {
                    var numberOfEntities = lookupEntities[entityUser.Key].Count();
                    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfEntities; i++)
                    {
                        var user = entityUser.Value.OrderBy(u => u.TotalEntities).First();
                        if (!user.EntitiesCount.ContainsKey(entityUser.Key))
                            user.EntitiesCount.Add(entityUser.Key, 0);
                        user.EntitiesCount[entityUser.Key]++;
                        user.TotalEntities++;
                    }

                }

                var averagePerUser = 0;
                var busyUsers = userList.Count(a => a.TotalEntities != 0);

                //Check to see if there is only one users assigned to each entity
                if (busyUsers != ignoreUsers)
                {
                    //Calculate the expected average per user 

                    var totalEntities = entities.Count;
                    averagePerUser = (totalEntities - ignoreEntities) / (busyUsers - ignoreUsers);

                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Total Entities: " + totalEntities);
                    Console.WriteLine("Average Entities: " + averagePerUser);
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    OutputAllocation(userList, averagePerUser);
                    var orderedUserList = userList.OrderByDescending(u => u.TotalEntities).ToList();
                    //Loop through the users and compare to the remaining users
                    for (var i = 0; i < orderedUserList.Count - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (var j = i + 1; j < userList.Count; j++)
                        {
                            BalanceUsers(userList[i], userList[j], entityUsers, averagePerUser);
                        }
                    }

                    ////Loop through the list in reverse order ?
                    //for (var i = userList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    //{
                    //    for (var j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                    //    {
                    //        BalanceUsers(userList[i], userList[j], entityUsers, averagePerUser);
                    //    }
                    //}
                }

                OutputAllocation(userList, averagePerUser);

                Console.WriteLine("Total assigned: " + userList.Sum(u => u.TotalEntities));
                Console.WriteLine();

                //Even out remaining difference across entity Type
                foreach (var entityUser in entityUsers.Where(a => a.Value.Count > 1))
                {
                    if (entityUser.Value.Any(u => (u.TotalEntities - averagePerUser > 0)))
                    {
                        var users = entityUser.Value.Where(u => (u.TotalEntities - averagePerUser != 0) && u.EntitiesCount[entityUser.Key] > 0);

                        var difference = 0;
                        foreach (var user in users)
                        {
                            difference += user.TotalEntities - averagePerUser;
                            user.TotalEntities -= difference;
                            user.EntitiesCount[entityUser.Key] -= difference;
                        }

                        List<User> fixUsers = null;
                        if (difference < 0)
                        {
                            fixUsers = entityUser.Value.Where(u => (u.EntitiesCount[entityUser.Key] > 0)).ToList();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fixUsers = entityUser.Value;
                        }
                        var change = difference / fixUsers.Count();
                        var userCount = fixUsers.Count();
                        foreach (var fixUser in fixUsers)
                        {
                            fixUser.TotalEntities += change;
                            fixUser.EntitiesCount[entityUser.Key] += change;
                            difference -= change;
                            userCount--;
                            //Correct change so that nothing gets lost
                            if (userCount != 0)
                                change = difference / userCount;
                            else
                                change = difference;

                        }
                    }
                }

                OutputAllocation(userList, averagePerUser);

                Console.WriteLine("Total assigned: " + userList.Sum(u => u.TotalEntities));
                Console.WriteLine();

                foreach (var lookupEntity in lookupEntities)
                {
                    Console.Write(lookupEntity.Key + " - " + lookupEntity.Count());
                    Console.Write(" Allocation: ");
                    foreach (User user in entityUsers[lookupEntity.Key])
                    {
                        Debug.Assert(user.EntitiesCount[lookupEntity.Key] >= 0);
                        Console.Write(user.userId + " = " + user.EntitiesCount[lookupEntity.Key] + "; ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void OutputAllocation(List<User> userList, int averagePerUser)
        {
            //Display allocation after initial assignment
            foreach (var user in userList)
            {
                var difference = user.TotalEntities - averagePerUser;
                if (user.Ignored)
                    Console.WriteLine("Assignment  " + user.userId + " has " + user.TotalEntities);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Assignment  " + user.userId + " has " + user.TotalEntities + " difference " + difference);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total assigned: " + userList.Sum(u => u.TotalEntities));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Compares two users and balances them out
        /// </summary>
        private static void BalanceUsers(User firstUser, User secondUser, Dictionary<string, List<User>> entityUsers, int averagePerWorker)
        {
            //Get the difference betweent the current users and the average worker
            var firstUserDiff = firstUser.TotalEntities - averagePerWorker;
            var secondUserDiff = secondUser.TotalEntities - averagePerWorker;


            //Get all the entities which the two users share
            var sharedEntityTypes = entityUsers.Where(x => x.Value.Contains(firstUser) && x.Value.Contains(secondUser)).Select(e => e.Key);

            foreach (var entityType in sharedEntityTypes)
            {
                var difference = firstUserDiff;

                if (firstUser.EntitiesCount.Count() > secondUser.EntitiesCount.Count())
                {
                    difference = -1 * secondUserDiff;
                }
                else if (firstUser.EntitiesCount.Count() == secondUser.EntitiesCount.Count())
                {
                    difference = firstUserDiff - secondUserDiff;
                }
                else
                {
                    difference = firstUserDiff;
                }

                difference = firstUserDiff;

                var maxAllowed = 0;
                if (difference > 0)
                {
                    maxAllowed = firstUser.EntitiesCount[entityType] > difference ? difference : firstUser.EntitiesCount[entityType];
                }
                else
                {
                    maxAllowed = secondUser.EntitiesCount[entityType] > Math.Abs(difference) ? difference : -1 * secondUser.EntitiesCount[entityType];
                }

                firstUser.EntitiesCount[entityType] -= maxAllowed;
                firstUser.TotalEntities -= maxAllowed;

                secondUser.EntitiesCount[entityType] += maxAllowed;
                secondUser.TotalEntities += maxAllowed;

                firstUserDiff = firstUser.TotalEntities - averagePerWorker;
                secondUserDiff = secondUser.TotalEntities - averagePerWorker;
            }
        }



        private static List<Entity> GenerateEntities(int maxEntityTypes, int totalEntities)
        {
            var entityTypes = new List<string>();
            for (var i = 0; i < maxEntityTypes; i++)
            {
                entityTypes.Add("E" + i);
            }
            var entities = new List<Entity>();
            Random random = new Random();
            for (var i = 0; i < totalEntities; i++)
            {
                //Randomly allocate user
                entities.Add(new Entity { Type = entityTypes[random.Next(maxEntityTypes)] });

                //Used to get even distribution
                //entities.Add(new Entity { Type = entityTypes[i%maxEntityTypes] });

                //Used to get specific ratio
                //var type = "";
                //switch (i % 3)
                //{
                //    case 0:
                //        type = "E0";
                //        break;
                //    case 1:
                //    case 2:
                //        type = "E1";
                //        break;
                //}

                //entities.Add(new Entity { Type = type });
            }
            return entities;


        }
    }
```

**Edit 1:**
I have made some changes to the code above.

1. Now when the entity list is created the program adds a list of random potential users to the entity, this should match your real world scenario better
2. The program now runs through all the entities and assigns them to a user based on which of the allowed users for that entity have the least entities
3. The program then will repeatedly try and balance the entities between the users until nothing changes

The code checks afterwards to make sure that the user assigned to an entity is actually in the prescribed users.

Sometimes the final results assignments is 1 or 2 entities different from the ideal case but all the entities are being assigned.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;


public class Entity
{
    public Entity()
    {
        _users = new List<User>();
    }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public List<User> _users;
    public List<User> Users
    {
        get
        {
            //You can add your rules for users here 
            return _users;
        }
    }
    public User AssignedUser { get; set; }

}

public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Entities = new Dictionary<string, Entity>();
    }
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    public int TotalEntities { get; set; }
    public bool Ignored { get; set; }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Load Entities, you can change the number of entities generated here
        int numEntityToGenerate = 50001;
        //Create users
        var userList = new List<User> {
                            new User { userId = "U0" } ,
                            new User { userId = "U1" } ,
                            new User { userId = "U2" } ,
                            new User { userId = "U3" } ,
                            new User { userId = "U4" } 
                        };
        userList = userList.OrderBy(u => u.userId).ToList();

        var entities = GenerateEntities(userList, numEntityToGenerate);

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            foreach (var user in entity.Users)
            {
                user.Entities.Add(entity.Type, null);
            }
        }

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            Console.Write(".");
            var user = entity.Users.OrderBy(u => u.TotalEntities).First();
            if (!user.Entities.ContainsKey(entity.Type))
                user.Entities.Add(entity.Type, null);
            user.Entities[entity.Type] = entity;
            user.TotalEntities++;
            entity.AssignedUser = user;
        }

        var averagePerUser = 0;
        var busyUsers = userList.Count(a => a.TotalEntities != 0);


        //Calculate the expected average per user 
        var totalEntities = entities.Count;
        averagePerUser = (totalEntities) / (busyUsers);

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Total Entities: " + totalEntities);
        Console.WriteLine("Average Entities: " + averagePerUser);
        Console.WriteLine("Busy Users: " + busyUsers);
        Console.WriteLine();

        List<int> oldDifference = null;
        List<int> newDifference = null;

        do
        {
            oldDifference = GetDifferenceList(userList, averagePerUser);
            OutputAllocation(userList, averagePerUser);
            var orderedUserList = userList.OrderByDescending(u => u.TotalEntities).ToList();
            //Loop through the users and compare to the remaining users
            for (var i = 0; i < orderedUserList.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (var j = i + 1; j < userList.Count; j++)
                {
                    BalanceUsers(userList[i], userList[j], entities, averagePerUser);
                }
            }
            newDifference = GetDifferenceList(userList, averagePerUser);
        } while (!Enumerable.SequenceEqual(oldDifference.OrderBy(t => t), newDifference.OrderBy(t => t)));


        Console.WriteLine("Total assigned: " + userList.Sum(u => u.TotalEntities));
        Console.WriteLine();

        OutputAllocation(userList, averagePerUser);

        Console.WriteLine("Total assigned: " + userList.Sum(u => u.TotalEntities));
        Console.WriteLine();


        //Check data quality
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            //Check to see if assigned user is valid
            Debug.Assert(entity.Users.Contains(entity.AssignedUser));
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static List<int> GetDifferenceList(List<User> userList, int averagePerUser)
    {
        var differences = new List<int>();

        foreach (var user in userList)
        {
            var difference = user.TotalEntities - averagePerUser;
            if (user.TotalEntities != 0)
                differences.Add(difference);
        }
        return differences;

    }

    private static void OutputAllocation(List<User> userList, int averagePerUser)
    {
        //Display allocation after initial assignment
        foreach (var user in userList)
        {
            var difference = user.TotalEntities - averagePerUser;
            if (user.TotalEntities == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Assignment  " + user.userId + " has " + user.TotalEntities);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Assignment  " + user.userId + " has " + user.TotalEntities + " difference " + difference);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Total assigned: " + userList.Sum(u => u.TotalEntities));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Compares two users and balances them out
    /// </summary>
    private static void BalanceUsers(User firstUser, User secondUser, List<Entity> entities, int averagePerWorker)
    {
        //Get the difference betweent the current users and the average worker
        var firstUserDiff = firstUser.TotalEntities - averagePerWorker;
        var secondUserDiff = secondUser.TotalEntities - averagePerWorker;


        if ((firstUserDiff != 0 && secondUserDiff != 0) && Math.Abs(firstUserDiff - secondUserDiff) > 1)
        {
            //Get all the entities which the two users share
            var sharedEntity = entities.Where(x => x.Users.Contains(firstUser) && x.Users.Contains(secondUser));

            foreach (var entity in sharedEntity)
            {
                //Find out the direction the change needs to occur
                if (firstUserDiff >= secondUserDiff)
                {
                    //Removing from firstUser so find out if it has the entity
                    if (firstUser.Entities[entity.Type] != null)
                    {
                        firstUser.Entities[entity.Type] = null;
                        firstUser.TotalEntities--;

                        secondUser.Entities[entity.Type] = entity;
                        secondUser.TotalEntities++;

                        entity.AssignedUser = secondUser;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //Removing from secondUser so find out if it has the entity
                    if (secondUser.Entities[entity.Type] != null)
                    {
                        firstUser.Entities[entity.Type] = entity;
                        firstUser.TotalEntities++;

                        secondUser.Entities[entity.Type] = null;
                        secondUser.TotalEntities--;

                        entity.AssignedUser = firstUser;
                    }
                }

                firstUserDiff = firstUser.TotalEntities - averagePerWorker;
                secondUserDiff = secondUser.TotalEntities - averagePerWorker;

                //Check to see if the two users have been balanced or if the difference is only one
                //IF that is the case break the for loop
                if ((firstUserDiff != 0 && secondUserDiff != 0) && (firstUserDiff == secondUserDiff) && Math.Abs(firstUserDiff - secondUserDiff) <= 1)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Generate a list of entities randomly adding a list of potential users to each entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userList">list of available users</param>
    /// <param name="totalEntities">Total number of entities required</param>
    /// <returns>A list of entities</returns>
    private static List<Entity> GenerateEntities(List<User> userList, int totalEntities)
    {
        var entities = new List<Entity>();
        Random random = new Random();
        for (var i = 0; i < totalEntities; i++)
        {
            var entity = new Entity { Type = "E" + (i + 1).ToString() };
            entities.Add(entity);

            //This code will either an entity to the last user or to a random list of users excluding the last one
            if (random.Next(12) == 0)
            {
                var user = userList[userList.Count() - 1];
                entity.Users.Add(user);
            }
            else
            {
                var numOfUsers = random.Next(2);

                for (var j = 0; j <= numOfUsers; j++)
                {
                    var user = userList[random.Next(userList.Count() - 1)];
                    if (!entity.Users.Contains(user))
                        entity.Users.Add(user);
                }
            }

            //if (i <= totalEntities / 2 )
            //{
            //    entity.Users.Add(userList[0]);
            //    entity.Users.Add(userList[1]);
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    entity.Users.Add(userList[2]);
            //    entity.Users.Add(userList[1]);
            //}

        }
        return entities;


    }
}
```

Comment: only problem is : E1 can be handled only by U1 or U2, like wise E2 => U3, U5 and E3 => U4, so the final allocation of any entity should only be within prespecified users

Comment: thanks a lot for taking time to write the code. though its doing a great job at balancing. but some problem.. its not  multiple entities per type, entities are unique so entities are from E1 to E50K, nothing repeated.

Comment: The current algorithm only gives an entity to a user that is specified to handle it.

Comment: only.. will check again.. thanks a lot btw for taking the time to work on it

Comment: If I understand correctly each entity will be specifying which user can handle it? So if you have E50k then there are 50K rules?

Comment: there are rules like `entity of type x can be handled by user of age > 45` etc. so in the end we get output as `E1 => U1 or U2` & `E2 => U2` & `E3 => U2 orU3` and so on... its just one example... there are around 100 rules like this which decides on per entity basis who can handled it for all 50K entities. which rule applies for that entity depends on that parameters defined in that entity, so as such there is no entity group, the evaluation is done on per entity basis

Comment: I added another code block with code that matches your scenario more closely

Comment: so the crux lies in `BalanceUsers`, which you loop thru on per user basis and balance.

Comment: Yes and that gets repeated until nothing changes
If you want to test different scenarios you can change the way the entities are setup in GenerateEntities

Answer (score 1):

I may be misunderstanding your problem your problem, but, from what I understand of your description, the problem seems pretty simple.

### On creating a new entity

```
Is that entity a "single user entity" ?
   Assign it to the given user
   : Assign it to the user that have the least number of entities. If you find users with the same number of instances, it doesn't matter, assign it to an arbitrary user.
```

### On realocating existing entities

If you want to "redistribute" allocated entities:

```
Take the number of entities you want to reallocate and divide it by the number of users and allocate them accordingly
```

Comment: reallocating is not a problem.. let me give you a scenario where the above simple logic, which I also implemented.. fails.. see the question edit...

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you maintain a TreeMap having  sorted based on CountOfEntities. Everytime you assign an entity to user at TreeMap(0) increment the CountOfEntities.

Comment: Sceario: Imagind i have 3 entires in Map <U1,1>, <U2,2>, <U3,3>. Now i will start assigning to first element ie <U1,1>. This will make <U1,2>,<U2,2>,<U3,3>, iteration 2: <U2,2>,<U1,3> <U3,3>, iteration 3: <U2,3>,<U1,3>,<U3,3>, iteration 4 : <U1,3>, <U3,3>, <U2,4>.. Almost equal distribution

Comment: but this does not solve the scenario given in edit of the question

Comment: you mean to say, u cant just randomly assign entities to users. THere is a designated rule on which user can work on which entity?

Comment: exactly.. there are designated rules, who can work on which items, see the EDIT2

Comment: probably once you have a sorted Set , you can loop through each user in incremental order and assign the entity. I.e if get the user with less entities assigned, check if current entity can be assigned to him, if not move to the next user who has less entities and try to assign.. i know this would be little performance overhead :( but just an alternative in case you want to use. Use TreeSet , in the User object have a variable CountOfEntities , write a comparator to sort on CountOfEntities property of the user. (Please consider this approach only as back up plan)